# Use variable in statement in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to use a variable in `{% include %}` statement in django templates. Specifically, I am trying to include a template in another template and i need to generate and pass url to be used in a button. How can I achieve this?

This is my troublesome part of `form.html` template:

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
        {% url 'accountant:gp_taxes:delete_rate' pk=field.value as delete_url %}
        {% include 'includes/formset_inline.html' with delete_url=delete_url %}
    </div>
```

and `formset_inline.html`:

```
<a class="btn btn-s btn-danger" href="{{ delete_url }}">
<i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;
</a>
```

When I look at the url in my browser it is empty (I have `<a class="btn btn-s btn-danger" href>`).

How can I pass the url?

**EDIT** clarification for topic added.

Comment: Are you trying to get the dynamic value of an input box to use as a URL? You can't do that with Django template tags.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing `inclusion tag` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags

```
@register.inclusion_tag('includes/formset_inline.html')
def formset_inline(delete_url):
    return {'delete_url': delete_url}
```

And then

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    {% url 'accountant:gp_taxes:delete_rate' pk=field.value as delete_url %}
    {% formset_inline delete_url %}
</div>
```