# Passing object to included template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this simple model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
    page_count = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I would like to render list of this model objects (passed to template as `book_copies`).

My (simplified) templates:

```
# 'books/list.html'
<div>
    {% for copy in book_copies %}
        {% include 'books/book.html' with book=copy only %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

and

```
# 'books/book.html'
<p>
    {{ book.title }} - {{ book.author }}
</p>
```

It seems that the template variable `copy` is passed to included template as a `str` representation of `Book` model. Therefore, I can't access its fields, e.g. `title` or `author`.

Is it possible to pass model object without conversion to included template?

Comment: This isn't right, the object should passed as is. Are you sure `book_copies` is actually a list of instances? Can you show how you get it in the first place?

Comment: `context['book_copies'] = Book.objects.all()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>
    {% for copy in book_copies %}
        {% include 'books/book.html' with author=copy.author title=copy.title only %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

you cant pass an object like that, but you can try this

Comment: I just wanted to not pass all fields one by one and was wondering whether there exists another method. Thank you :)

Comment: yeah i can understand that from your question, but unfortunately there is nothing to pass a whole object

Comment: @Nuurek there are custom inclusion tags https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags here is example https://stackoverflow.com/a/44627440/3627387

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Yes, I've seen them and are using them right now. Asked the question out of curiousity and code simplicity :)

Comment: Why can't you pass an object? Could you point to the documentation for that @Exprator?